# Problems returning unique values from two tables with union and Row_Number in SQL

Tags: sql, union, common-table-expression, sql-server-2016, row-number

I am trying to return the unique values from one field “name” from two tables using union and Row_number.

I need to return three columns: ID, Caseid and Name but only the unique names.  The same name appears in both View1 and Table2 multiple times.

The ID is also unique so I can’t use group by to achieve this.

Below is my attempt which I hoped would assign row no 1 to the first result of each name however it isn’t working and providing strange results e.g. where there are two identical names it can give a row number of 52.  Other results work as intending.

**Saved as NewDistinctView**

```
WITH cte1 AS 
(
SELECT  ID, Caseid, Title as Name
FROM           View1
UNION 
SELECT        ID, CaseID, Name as Name
FROM          Table2
WHERE        (Party = 'Yes')),
cte2 as (SELECT ID, Caseid, Name,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY ID DESC) AS rn
from cte1
)
SELECT       *
FROM         cte2
WHERE       rn = 1
```

**Table2**

```
    ID      CASEID         NAME       PARTY  
 -------- ----------- -------------- ------- 
  116524   486628439   Fiona T        No     
  116525   486628439   DTZ Holdings   Yes    
  384221   486628439   Clare S        Yes    
  384222   486628439   David S        YES    
  384223   486628439   Andrew P       YES
```

**View1**

```
  ID     CASEID        TITLE      
 ----- ----------- -------------- 
  591   486628439   DTZ Holdings  
  594   486628439   DTZ Holdings  
  592   486628439   Clare S       
  593   486628439   David S       
  595   486628439   David S       
  584   486628439   John B        
  585   486628439   John B        
  586   486628439   Anna A        
  587   486628439   Peter D       
  588   486628439   Peter D       
  589   486628439   Peter D       
  590   486628439   Peter D
```

**Results when "where rn = 1" is changed to "rn > 0" to show all rn**

With a * next to the erroneous results

```
    ID      CASEID         NAME       RN  
 -------- ----------- -------------- ---- 
     592   486628439   Clare S        52*  
     593   486628439   David S         8*  
     584   486628439   John B          2  
     589   486628439   Peter D         2  
  384221   486628439   Clare S         1  
  384222   486628439   David S         1  
  116525   486628439   DTZ Holdings    3  
     586   486628439   Anna A          1  
     588   486628439   Peter D         3  
  384223   486628439   Andrew P        1  
     595   486628439   David S         7*  
     591   486628439   DTZ Holdings    5*  
     585   486628439   John B          1  
     590   486628439   Peter D         1  
     594   486628439   DTZ Holdings    4  
     587   486628439   Peter D         4
```

If "where rn = 1" is used to display unique results then Clare S is not displayed, but the rn is still not functioning as intended.

I would appreciate any thoughts on how I can achieve this as an amendment of the below or by another method?  I am using SQL Server 2016.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: "Not working" and "providing strange results" do not give much guidance.  Can you show sample data and a (perhaps simplified) result set showing the problem?

Comment: and please provide proper formatting of the script

Comment: why don't you have `WHERE (PARTY = 'Yes')` is the first select as well?

Comment: I have edited the main post to tidy up the formatting and include sample data and results.  The where party = Yes is used to filter out results from table 2, view 1 does not have a column "party".

Comment: It's definitely a bug, check if it's fixed by the latest service pack.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have control to install the latest service pack.  Also, changing the order by in "PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY ID DESC" to order by name gives completely different, also erroneous rn results.  If it is a bug, is there an alternative way to achieve what I am trying to do i.e. only display the unique names from both tables? Thanks

Comment: Run your statement without the `WHERE rn = 1` clause, and check the output. Are there actually 52 rows for Clare S with ID = 592? If so, then your query is working correctly. If not, then there is a bug.  NOTE: Just because the data is known to be X is no reason to not verify it. I've found more problems with this simple step than you could believe. In fact, running `SELECT ID, Caseid, Name FROM cte1 ORDER BY ID, Name` would be best.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ID is Primary Key even after the union of the two tables, this should work:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.CaseID, A.Name
FROM cte1 A
JOIN (SELECT Name, MAX(ID) AS ID
    FROM cte1
    GROUP BY Name) B
ON A.ID = B.ID
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is still showing duplicate results.  It also automatically added the as statements and parts in bold.
from cte1 **AS cte1_1**
GROUP BY name) **AS** B ON A.ID = B.ID